# mysql return numbers of specific row?

Tags: php, mysql

In my mysql table i have table that contain points, a want to return number of that table?

Can some one help me?

```
("select * from liv_sr")


Table contain(id,name,ip,port,*rank*....)
```

I want to "rank" return in numbers, specifik number 
Etc.(1,2,3,500)

```
query[0]['rank']=1200 points=>1 on rank
query[1]['rank']=800 points=>2 on rank
query[2]['rank']=1 points=>500 on rank
```

Comment: Is ur table points a different table or part of the primary table whose structure you have shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a order by query

```
$sql="select * from table order by rank desc";
$point =1;
$result = mysql_query($sql); 
$tableResult = array();
while($arrayresult =mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $tableResult[] = array('id'=>$arrayresult['id'],'rank'=>$arrayresult['rank'],'point'=>$point);
    $point= $point+1;
}
```

Comment: Thankx it is help me, but one more think

foreach($tableResult as $rr){
 echo $rr['point'];   **RETURN result
        echo $rr['id']; **RETURN nothing
}
And one more think in some one profile write rank, how to return value of that? tnx man :)

Comment: mc.storm-hq.com is project on, you can see page "serveri" and some server have rank you whill see :P

Comment: @maki10 If your question is answered, please post another question if you have any

Comment: table contain (id,ip,port,name and 7 more columbs)

Comment: do a print_r for arrayresult and add keys of arrayresult  which you need in ur tableresult array

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is already answered, but if you really want to achieve having only one result row, you could have a look at MySQL group_concat. In your example, you could get a result of say for example:

"1200, 600, 500" (comma seperated, ordered by ranked) with

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(rank ORDER BY rank DESC SEPARATOR ', ') FROM liv_sr GROUP BY 'all'
```

In php, you could split the result with:

```
$myArray = explode(',', $result);
```

Also, note that there's 1024 byte limit on result. If you need more, than simple run:

```
SET group_concat_max_len = 2048
```